# How can I remove super glue from a table saw deck?

Tags: cleaning, adhesive, table-saw

Apparently some super glue has spilled on the table of my table saw. Quite a large amount. The table appears to be a hard plastic, its a Dewalt 8" saw.

Is there anyway to get this off without destroying the table?

Its completely dry and about ⅛" thick.
[image: glue on table saw]
[image: glue on table saw]

Comment: The usual solvent for super glue is acetone - a.k.a. nail-polish remover. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Some plastics are affected by acetone. I'd do a test underneath.

Comment: Superglue type adhesives don't adhere well to many plastics especially HDPE.  You might try peeling it off.

Comment: Acetone didn't really help. Found out the hard way the table is indeed metal with some type of coating. I used a glass scraper to remove as much as I could, put a small gouge in the table. Finished it off with a random orbital and 220 sandpaper.

Answer (score 2):

Since the table's plastic, you'll want to stay away from any solvents to remove the glue as they will probably dissolve part of the table. I think your best bet is to get a flat sanding disk mounted to your drill and use the edge of the spinning disk to lightly sand away the glue. Make sure to wear a good mask when doing the sanding. Using the edge will give you good control of what you're removing and spare the table.

Comment: You're almost guaranteed to put crescents in your table this way. I'd use a hard sanding block or a random-orbit sander.

Comment: @isherwood  Those would be good too. I've used the drill and sanding disks and with a fine grit and light touch have had good results.